# ¿Cómo puedo poner a un a imagen diferente tamaño con Bootstrap?

Tags: html, bootstrap

Estoy desarrollando un programa de un CRM al cual le he añadido un archivo png de muy grandes dimensiones. Sé que en Bootstrap puede modificar los tamaños con `h` y `w` (`height` y `width`) además de que funcionan con porcentajes o de forma automática.

El punto es que no sé como hacer para que dependiendo del tamaño de la pantalla de un dispositivo tenga por ejemplo el ancho de `25%` y que en otra pantalla, al ser mas grande tenga el `50%` o `75%`, para controlar el tamaño usa una clase llamado `w-25`:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Visitas</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <style>
        .container {
            border: 1px solid blue;
        }

        .row {
            border: 1px solid red;
        }

        .col {
            border: 1px solid salmon
        }

        .alineacion {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-2Pmvv0kuTBOenSvLm6bvfBSSHrUJ+3A7x6P5Ebd07/g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="Javascript/visitas.js"></script>

    <nav class="py-2 bg-info border-bottom">
    <div class="container d-flex flex-wrap bg-info">
      <ul class="nav me-auto my-1">
        <li class="nav-item mx-1"><a href="#" class="nav-link link-body-emphasis px-2 active bg-light rounded" aria-current="page">Ver Visitas</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mx-1"><a href="#" class="nav-link link-body-emphasis px-2 bg-light rounded">Añadir Cliente/trabajador</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mx-1"><a href="#" class="nav-link link-body-emphasis px-2 bg-light rounded">Programar vista</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item mx-1"><a href="#" class="nav-link link-body-emphasis px-2 bg-light rounded">Ver Rechazadas</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav my-1" >
        <li class="nav-item mx-1"><a href="#" class="nav-link link-body-emphasis px-2 bg-danger text-white rounded">Cerrar Session</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <header class="py-3 mb-4 border-bottom">
        <div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center" >
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 alineacion">
                <a class="alineacion"><img src="assets/CAB.png"  alt="" class="fs-4 w-25"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 alineacion ">
                <form class="d-flex input-group w-75 align-middle">
                <input type="search" id="search" class="form-control rounded" aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="search-addon" />
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary px-3 me-2">
                    buscar
                </button>
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table align-middle mb-0 bg-white">
                    <thead class="bg-light">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Motivo</th>
                            <th>Estado</th>
                            <th>Fecha Solicitada</th>
                            <th>A cargo</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="contenedor">
                        <?php
                        include('<controladores/conexion.php');
                        $tabla = $RMC->query('SELECT * FROM visita');
                        if ($tabla) //si la consulta es correcta
                        {
                            $contenido = $tabla->fetch_object();
                            while ($contenido != null) //mientras trenga contenido
                            {
                                if ($contenido->estado == "pendiente") {
                                    echo "<tr taskId=\"$contenido->id\">";
                                    echo "
                                <td>
                                <div class=\"d-flex align-items-center\">
                                    <div class=\"ms-3\">
                                        <p class=\"fw-bold mb-1\">$contenido->cliente</p>
                                        <p class=\"text-muted mb-0\">$contenido->empresa</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </td>";
                                    echo "
                                <td>
                                <p class=\"fw-normal mb-1\">$contenido->motivo</p>
                                </td>";
                                    echo "
                                <td>
                                <span class=\"\">$contenido->estado</span>
                                </td>";
                                    echo "
                                <td>
                                <p class=\"fw-normal mb-1\">$contenido->fecha</p>
                                </td>";
                                    echo "
                                <td>
                                <p class=\"fw-normal mb-1\">$contenido->trabajador</p>
                                </td>";
                                    echo "
                                <td>
                                <button type=\"button\" class=\"task-done btn btn-success btn-sm btn-rounded\">
                                    hecho
                                </button>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button type=\"button\" class=\"task-delete btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-rounded\">
                                    borrar
                                </button>
                            </td>
                                ";
                                } else {
                                    echo "<tr taskId=\"$contenido->id\">";
                                    echo "
                                    <td>
                                    <div class=\"d-flex align-items-center\">
                                        <div class=\"ms-3\">
                                            <p class=\"fw-bold mb-1\">$contenido->cliente</p>
                                            <p class=\"text-muted mb-0\">$contenido->empresa</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </td>";
                                    echo "
                                    <td>
                                    <p class=\"fw-normal mb-1\">$contenido->motivo</p>
                                    </td>";
                                    echo "
                                    <td>
                                    <span class=\"\">$contenido->estado</span>
                                    </td>";
                                    echo "
                                    <td>
                                    <p class=\"fw-normal mb-1\">$contenido->fecha</p>
                                    </td>";
                                    echo "
                                    <td>
                                    <p class=\"fw-normal mb-1\">$contenido->trabajador</p>
                                    </td>";
                                    echo "
                                    <td>
                                    <button type=\"button\" class=\"task-pend btn btn-warning btn-sm btn-rounded\">
                                        pendiente
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button type=\"button\" class=\"task-delete btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-rounded\">
                                        borrar
                                    </button>
                                </td>
                                    ";
                                }
                                $contenido = $tabla->fetch_object();
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Aquí hay imágenes para explicar bien mi problema. En esta imagen está con la foto al `25%`:

[image: En esta imagen esta con la foto al 25%]

Y si reduzco mi pantalla, me queda así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Apenas se aprecia mi logo.

Comment: Checa la documentación. [Images - Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/content/images/)

Comment: lo estoy viendo pero, no encuentro un ejemplo que me ayude a solucionar mi problema

Comment: ¿De verdad no te sirve _img-fluid_?

Comment: No me sirve, por que la imagen es muy grande, img fluid me sirve para otra que se haga adaptativo

Comment: ¿Y el problema es que se ve muy pequeña tu imagen en dispositivos pequeños?... ¿Cuál es tu resultado esperado?... además, ¿Qué versión de Bootstrap estás utilizando?...

Comment: Estoy usando la version 5.3 de Bootstrap, y no es que se vea pequeña, se ve muy pequeña, tanto que apenas se lee las letras del logo

Comment: ¿Y si le colocas un ancho fijo a tu imagen? por ejemplo: `width: 150px`...

Comment: Partamos por lo básico, que es colocar un [MRE]. Tu problema no tiene nada que ver con PHP, no tiene porque haber rastros de ese lenguaje en el código de ejemplo

Comment: Cuando usas la clase img-fluid lo que hace es que toma el ancho máximo del contenedor padre. Dicho esto, olvídate del ancho de la imagen y aplicarle clases a ella. Enfócate en las clases responsivas que ya nombraste (w-100, w-50) pero aplicadas al contenedor de la imagen. PD: Elimina ese CSS personalizado, al agregar border estás complicandole a Bootstrap el cálculo responsivo, es como si añadieras pixeles de más, donde ya hay un ancho definido que se mide en porcentaje.